# If Manufacturer's product formula is: $q=10\sqrt{m^2+4900}-700$ should you hire the 241st employee? (Relative Rate of Change)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, economics

> A manufacturer has found that when m employees are working, the number of units of product per day is $q=10\sqrt{m^2+4900}-700$. The demand equation for the product is $8q + p^2 -19300 = 0$, where $p$ is the selling price when the demand for the product is $q$ units per day.
>
> 1. Determine the manufacturer's marginal-revenue product when $m = 240$
> 2. Find the relative rate of change of revenue with respect to number of employees when $m = 240$
> 3. Suppose it would cost the manufacturer $400$ more per day to hire an additional employee. Would you hire the $241$ st employee, why or why not?
>
> Notes: Marginal-revenue product formula is Marginal Revenue $\cdot$ Marginal Product.
> Marginal is another way of saying rate of change so it is the derivative. And revenue $= p \cdot q$.

So, I solved all three of them but I just want another eye to check it - it is kinda important.

Here is the solution with proper form:

1.$\text{MRP} = \text{MR} \cdot \text{MP}$ ,$p = \sqrt{19300-8q}$

On substituting $m=240$ into $q$ product function: $q=10\sqrt{240^2+4900}-700 = 1800$

$$ \begin{align} \text{R} &= p \cdot q \\
&= \sqrt{19300-8q} \cdot q\\
&= \sqrt{19300q^2-8q^3}  \end{align}$$

$$\text{MR} = \text{R'} = \frac{19300q-12q^2}{\sqrt{19300q^2-8q^3}}$$  On substituting $q = 1800$  $$ \text{MR} = -32.86$$

Then to find the $\text{MP}$,$$ \text{MP} = q' = \frac{10m}{\sqrt{m^2+4900}}$$ On substituting $m = 240$  $$\text{MP} = 9.6$$

Then $$\text{MRP} = \text{MR} \cdot \text{ MP} = -32.86 \cdot 9.6 = -315.43$$

2.Relative Rate of change is $\frac{ \text{MR}}{\text{R}}$, and for $m = 240$, I found $p=70$ and $q=1800$. Then $$\text{R} = p \cdot q = 70 \cdot 1800 = 126000$$
$$ \implies \frac{\text{MR}}{\text{R}} = \frac{-32.86}{126000} = -0.00026 $$

Especially I have doubts about the second part of the question. When it says find the relative rate of change with respect to m do I need to use $\frac{dR}{dm} * \frac{dq}{dm}$ or what I did is fine?

3. I wouldn't advise since the marginal revenue is negative which means the $241$st employee will bring negative revenue.

Comment: Use mathjax instead of pictures please!

Comment: I added the mathjax form, too. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: when finding $MR$, $-24q^2$ must be $-12q^2$.

Comment: Ahh, yeah I just saw that I forgot to divide that one by 2. Thank you so much man, it changes every value!